# PYTHON: returning one dimensional list from strings and vice versa

Tags: python-3.x

How to build one dimensional list from string and build string from a list?

Suppose **input** string is: `STACKOVERFLOW`
then the **output list** should be `outputList = [S,T,A,C,K,O,V,E,R,F,L,O,W]`

and if **input list** is `inputList = [S,T,A,C,K,O,V,E,R,F,L,O,W]`
the **output** should be a `string = STACKOVERFLOW`

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:51:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = "STACKOVERFLOW"
>>> l = [c for c in s] # Or just list(s), as noted below by agf
>>> l
['S', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'O', 'W']
>>> ''.join(l)
'STACKOVERFLOW'
```

**EDITED** to show agf's comment, below.

Comment: Thanks Weetu for the reply.  What does it mean l = [c for c in s]

Comment: @nischalinn The proper way to get a list from a string `s` is just `list(s)`

Comment: @nischalinn: That's a list comprehension. See http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions